# Regular expression with * as a "word character"

Tags: .net, regex

I have some text that consists of space separated arbitrary-length codes, example:

```
AA *X IJ XYZ 7F *A OF *B 3C
```

As a first step, I want to extract all of the codes that are 2 characters where the first character is an asterisk, and the second character is one of 3 different alternatives (let's say they're A, B & C).  So after this step, in this example I would have as my list of matches `*A` and `*B`.

I tried using the following regex

```
\b(\*[ABC])\b
```

...but of course, that doesn't work because the asterisk isn't considered part of a word.  How can I do this in a readable, maintainable manner?

Comment: I'm glad you already have an answer but for my sake can you elaborate on the problem? Because I don't see the need for matching `\b` here when `\s(\*[ABC])\s` works just fine.

Comment: @ByteBlast that wouldn't match at the start or end of the string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind, and match either the begining of the string or a space character:

```
(<=^| )(\*[ABC])\b
```

See it here in action: http://regex101.com/r/wS5qS2

---

If all you care about is the capture group, you don't need the lookbehind. Just keep it out of your capture group:

```
(?:^| )(\*[ABC])\b
```